# User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. - Google Analytics API v4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer, google-analytics-4

I've created a few Google Analytics V4 only properties a while ago.

Big mistake.

I'm using Google Spreadsheets to track the progress and such, and had to waste time migrating the API for it using OAuth2 and the [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)

All went fine. Until a few weeks ago when it stopped working. I see there's a new version, [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)

I've procrastinated, so I'm doing the migration now, but hit a brick wall:

> *"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."*

I don't understand why I get this issue. Remade the credential in the developer console, redone the Oauth2 process, recreated the tokens, checked everything still this issue.

So I decided trying the "Try this API", I get into the same issue

[image]
[image]

Which is weird, I'm logging in using the analytics admin account. Also this error is weird:

> *"This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0."*,

since I'm basically logging in using the provided pop-up

[image]

The view id I took from here:

[image]

I've tried with any ID I could find (yeah, even MEASUREMENT ID and STREAM ID) and multiple sites (views)

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not the code from the try me, which may or may not have been updated to the Beta version of the Data api.  BTW the Data api is under development you understand that its changing a lot and is really not stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## your error

> "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Basically means that the user you are authenticating with does not have permission to access the view id you are using.  Authorize your code with user that has access to it.  I have a video on this [User doesn't have any google analytics accounts easy solution](https://youtu.be/s0fwl7tbS8U)

## confusion

I am however a little confused as to what you are doing.  Your code says that you are using the Google Analytics reporting api, your using a view id which implies that this is a universal analytics account.

Yet you are trying to use the Google analytics data api which is intended for use with Google Analytics GA4 accounts.  
[Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)
 and won't work with your universal analytics account with a view id, it only works with the new Google Analytics GA4 accounts.

Comment: I'm using the v4 of the analytics, not the Universal Analytics. The account is Admin account. Writing this I've just realized the sheer stupidity of Google nomenclature and my error. Analytics Reporting V4 doesn't work on analytics version 4 and is exclusive for version 3. Google Fuuuuuu !

Comment: @NertanLucian Your not the only one to complain about the naming of this new system i put up a tweet about it last week because yours is not the first question i have answered about this.  I actually ended up putting up a tutorial last night because of your question [Guide to Google analytics Data Api Beta with C#.](https://www.daimto.com/export-data-from-google-analytics-4-with-c/)

Comment: Update: I sent out a ping to the team to find out if they have even created a library for apps script yet  for admin and data apis.   I did a bit of digging and i cant find them.